# Understanding of underlying probability space for two random variables with the same law

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

If the sample space is a subset of the real line, random variables $X$ and $Y$ are equal in distribution (denoted $X \overset{d}{=}  Y$) if they have the same distribution functions:
$\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)= \mathbb{P}(Y\leq x)$ for every $x$. Also, we know to be equal in distribution, random variables need not be defined on the same (underlying) probability space.
My question would be, since $X$ and $Y$ can be defined on different underlying spaces, why does it make sense for us to write things like $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)= \mathbb{P}(Y\leq x)$? Since, here we could equip different probability measures to the underlying spaces, why we don't write it as $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)= \mathbb{Q}(Y\leq x)$, if we equip the underlying space for $Y$ with probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: To be equal in distribution $X$ and $Y$ do not have to be defined on the same underlying probability space. We simply say that they have the same CDF i.e. satisfy $\mathbb P(X\le x)=\mathbb Q(Y\le x)\,.$ See the [usual suspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Equality_in_distribution).

Comment: @KurtG.  But here why can we simply replace $X$ with $Y$ under probability $\mathbb{P}$, i.e. why we have $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq x)=\mathbb{Q}(Y\leq x)$? Actually, I am not sure even writing $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq x)$ make sense, since $\mathbb{P}$ is NOT the probability measure we put on the space that $Y$ is defined.

Comment: @Harry Implicit in the definition of random variable is that not only is $X$ a function $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$, there is also a probability measure $\mu$ on $\Omega$ that we associate with $X$. From this point of view, a random variable is a pair $(X,\mu)$. On the other hand, $\mathbb P(X\leq x) = \mathbb P(Y\leq x)$ is a convenient abuse of notation, meaning that $\mu(X\leq x) = \nu(Y\leq x)$.

Comment: @Andrew like you said  measure $\mu$ is defined on $\Omega$ and so is $X$, while $Y$ could be defined on a different space, say $\Omega$’ on which the measure we associated to could be very different than $\mu$ so abusing the notation here doesn’t make too much sense to me. If they are defined on the same underlying space, then I fully agree. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Andrew when $X$ and $Y$ do not live on the same probability space that notation is so wrong that speaking of it as a convenient abuse is a gross understatement.

Comment: @Harry : You can remove the first sentence of your question "If the sample space is a subset of the real line" since that is irrelevant. Often it is assumed there is one probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$ so the random variables $X,Y$ are on that space. If you want to consider $(\Omega_1, F_1, P_1)$ and $(\Omega_2, F_2, P_2)$ you would indeed say either $P_1[X_1\leq x] = P_2[X_2\leq x]$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (or you can call $P_2[\cdot]$ your probability measure $Q[\cdot]$ if you like), or equivalently $F_{X_1}(x)=F_{X_2}(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @KurtG. : I can see from your wikipedia link that the question is itself directly taken from the wording of that link. This is a rare case when the wikipedia entry is poorly written (it gives an irrelevant requirement that the sample space is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, it fails to use $P_1$ and $P_2$ if there are different probability spaces).  This is what seems to be motivating the question itself.

Comment: @Michael I refuse to be associated with wikipedia links who are mostly poorly written, nonetheless convenient sometimes. Thanks for writing a comment that clarifies things by taking different probability spaces.